# How to pass multiple Base64 code into Html through Javascript Loop based on JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am converting Base64 into the image in `html`. I am using `javascript` and `html` only.  I am getting all base64 code through `JSON` Array. But right now I am hard coding base64 the with `jQuery`.

```js
   $('#firstImage').attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,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');
$('#seondImage').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,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');
$('#thirdImage').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,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');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <input type="radio" id="white" class="radio-custom" value="">
     <label for="white" class="radio-custom-label">First Image</label>
     <input type="radio" id="nearIR" class="radio-custom" value="">
     <label for="nearIR" class="radio-custom-label">Second Image</label>
     <input type="radio" id="ultra" class="radio-custom" value="">
     <label for="ultra" class="radio-custom-label">Third Image</label>
</div>
              
<div class="img-wrap">
      <img id="firstImage" src="" alt="first Image">
      <img id="seondImage" src="" alt="second image">
      <img id="thirdImage" src="" alt="third image">                
</div>
```

In above code I hard coded all base64 in javascript. But I want to make it as dynamic.
**Below is the JSON format**

```
{
"type": "images",   
"allowedattemptcount": 3,
"ricdata": [{
    "ImageData": [{
            "PropertyValue": "firstImage",
            "PropertyName": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwHVYZ/z595kzAP/s7P+goOXMv8+fhw/v739/f+8PD98fH/8mJl+fn/9ZWb8/PzWlwv///6wWGbImAPgTEMImIN9gUFCEm/gDALULDN8PAD6atYdCTX9gUNKlj8wZAKUsAOzZz+UMAOsJAP/Z2ccMDA8PD/95eX5NWvsJCOVNQPtfX/8zM8+QePLl38MGBr8JCP+zs9myn/8GBqwpAP/GxgwJCPny78lzYLgjAJ8vAP9fX/+MjMUcAN8zM/9wcM8ZGcATEL+QePdZWf/29uc/P9cmJu9MTDImIN+/r7+/vz8/P8VNQGNugV8AAF9fX8swMNgTAFlDOICAgPNSUnNWSMQ5MBAQEJE3QPIGAM9AQMqGcG9vb6MhJsEdGM8vLx8fH98AANIWAMuQeL8fABkTEPPQ0OM5OSYdGFl5jo+Pj/+pqcsTE78wMFNGQLYmID4dGPvd3UBAQJmTkP+8vH9QUK+vr8ZWSHpzcJMmILdwcLOGcHRQUHxwcK9PT9DQ0O/v70w5MLypoG8wKOuwsP/g4P/Q0IcwKEswKMl8aJ9fX2xjdOtGRs/Pz+Dg4GImIP8gIH0sKEAwKKmTiKZ8aB/f39Wsl+LFt8dgUE9PT5x5aHBwcP+AgP+WltdgYMyZfyywz78AAAAAAAD///8AAP9mZv///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAKgALAAAAAA9AEQAAAj/AFEJHEiwoMGDCBMqXMiwocAbBww4nEhxoYkUpzJGrMixogkfGUNqlNixJEIDB0SqHGmyJSojM1bKZOmyop0gM3Oe2liTISKMOoPy7GnwY9CjIYcSRYm0aVKSLmE6nfq05QycVLPuhDrxBlCtYJUqNAq2bNWEBj6ZXRuyxZyDRtqwnXvkhACDV+euTeJm1Ki7A73qNWtFiF+/gA95Gly2CJLDhwEHMOUAAuOpLYDEgBxZ4GRTlC1fDnpkM+fOqD6DDj1aZpITp0dtGCDhr+fVuCu3zlg49ijaokTZTo27uG7Gjn2P+hI8+PDPERoUB318bWbfAJ5sUNFcuGRTYUqV/3ogfXp1rWlMc6awJjiAAd2fm4ogXjz56aypOoIde4OE5u/F9x199dlXnnGiHZWEYbGpsAEA3QXYnHwEFliKAgswgJ8LPeiUXGwedCAKABACCN+EA1pYIIYaFlcDhytd51sGAJbo3onOpajiihlO92KHGaUXGwWjUBChjSPiWJuOO/LYIm4v1tXfE6J4gCSJEZ7YgRYUNrkji9P55sF/ogxw5ZkSqIDaZBV6aSGYq/lGZplndkckZ98xoICbTcIJGQAZcNmdmUc210hs35nCyJ58fgmIKX5RQGOZowxaZwYA+JaoKQwswGijBV4C6SiTUmpphMspJx9unX4KaimjDv9aaXOEBteBqmuuxgEHoLX6Kqx+yXqqBANsgCtit4FWQAEkrNbpq7HSOmtwag5w57GrmlJBASEU18ADjUYb3ADTinIttsgSB1oJFfA63bduimuqKB1keqwUhoCSK374wbujvOSu4QG6UvxBRydcpKsav++Ca6G8A6Pr1x2kVMyHwsVxUALDq/krnrhPSOzXG1lUTIoffqGR7Goi2MAxbv6O2kEG56I7CSlRsEFKFVyovDJoIRTg7sugNRDGqCJzJgcKE0ywc0ELm6KBCCJo8DIPFeCWNGcyqNFE06ToAfV0HBRgxsvLThHn1oddQMrXj5DyAQgjEHSAJMWZwS3HPxT/QMbabI/iBCliMLEJKX2EEkomBAUCxRi42VDADxyTYDVogV+wSChqmKxEKCDAYFDFj4OmwbY7bDGdBhtrnTQYOigeChUmc1K3QTnAUfEgGFgAWt88hKA6aCRIXhxnQ1yg3BCayK44EWdkUQcBByEQChFXfCB776aQsG0BIlQgQgE8qO26X1h8cEUep8ngRBnOy74E9QgRgEAC8SvOfQkh7FDBDmS43PmGoIiKUUEGkMEC/PJHgxw0xH74yx/3XnaYRJgMB8obxQW6kL9QYEJ0FIFgByfIL7/IQAlvQwEpnAC7DtLNJCKUoO/w45c44GwCXiAFB/OXAATQryUxdN4LfFiwgjCNYg+kYMIEFkCKDs6PKAIJouyGWMS1FSKJOMRB/BoIxYJIUXFUxNwoIkEKPAgCBZSQHQ1A2EWDfDEUVLyADj5AChSIQW6gu10bE/JG2VnCZGfo4R4d0sdQoBAHhPjhIB94v/wRoRKQWGRHgrhGSQJxCS+0pCZbEhAAOw=="
        },
        {
            "PropertyValue": "data:image/png;base64,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",
            "PropertyName": "secondImage"
        },
        {
            "PropertyValue": "data:image/png;base64,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",
            "PropertyName": "thirdImage"
        }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I want to put into loop that `propertyName` and `propertyValue`, and parse into UI. Because in future fourth object may be come into `json`. So need to write again mapping with key fields. Right now I am hard coding with `jquery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is to loop your JSON object and make the desired structure like this:

```
const myJson = JSON.parse(myJsonObject);
myJson.ricdata[0].ImageData.forEach( ele => {
   // if you need to create an image element:
   $('body').appendChild("<img id="+ele.PropertyName+" src="+ele.PropertyValue+" />")

   // OR if you already have the html strucured:
   $('#'+ele.PropertyName).attr('src', ele.PropertyValue);
});
```